# R shiny renderplot returns a blank plot with only x and y corrdinates

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing shiny program that is supposed to display a plot with x axis being the sample size and y being the corresponding power. Since the power needs to be calculated for each value of sample size ranging from n/2 to 2n, I used a for loop inside the reactive part. 
here is the code:

I cannot figure out why the output gives me a blank plot which has only the coordinates without any points on it. I guess there is something wrong with the two vectors (`samplesize1` and `powervector1`) that I want to be shown on the plot, but I didn't understand why they are not showing up in the picture.

Could someone help me figure this out?

```
library('shiny')

ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Sample Size Calculation"),

  numericInput("num1", 
               h3("Power to be reached"), 
               value = 0.85, min=0, max=1,step=0.01),

  numericInput("num2", 
               h3("Scale parameter"),value=25,step=0.1),

  numericInput("num3", 
               h3("delta"), 
               value = 2,step=0.01),

  numericInput("num4", 
               h3("allocation ratio"), 
               value = 1,min=0, step=0.01),


  numericInput("num5", 
               h3("Beta"), 
               value = 0.1062, min=0, step=0.01),

  numericInput("num6", 
               h3("event probability"), 
               value = 1,min=0, max=1,step=0.01),

  numericInput("num7", 
               h3("Significant level"), 
               value = 0.05, min=0, max=1,step=0.01),

  plotOutput("picture"),
  textOutput("k_gamma"),
  submitButton("Submit")

)

server<-function(input,output){
  n=2
  power1=rep(NA,2*n)
  ndf=rep(NA,2*n)
  ddf=rep(NA,2*n)
  f_crit1=rep(NA,2*n)
  f_crit2=rep(NA,2*n)
  criticalvalue1=rep(NA,2*n)
  criticalvalue2=rep(NA,2*n)
  x=rep(NA,2*n)

  my_func<-reactive({
    k_gamma<-input$num2
    delta_pt<-input$num3
    r<-input$num4
    beta<-input$num5
    eventprob<-input$num4
    alpha<-input$num7


    for (i in 1:(2*n)) {

      ndf[i]=2*ceiling(eventprob*i)*k_gamma
      ddf[i]=2*ceiling(eventprob*i)*r*k_gamma
      f_crit1[i]= qf(1-alpha,ndf[i],ddf[i])
      f_crit2[i] = qf(alpha,ndf[i],ddf[i])
      criticalvalue1[i]=(f_crit1[i]*r)/((delta_pt**(beta)))
      criticalvalue2[i]=(f_crit2[i]*r)/((delta_pt**(beta)))
      power1[i]=1-pf(criticalvalue1[i],ndf[i],ddf[i])+pf(criticalvalue2[i],ndf[i],ddf[i])
      samplesize1=c(ceiling(n/2):(2*n))
      powervector1=power1[ceiling(n/2):(2*n)]

    }

  })

  output$picture<-renderPlot({plot(my_func()$samplesize1, my_func()$powervector1 ,xlim=c(0,200),ylim=c(0,1))})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `my_func` needs to return a named list with at least power and sample size: `list(samplesize1 = samplesize1, powervector1 = powervector1)`

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you, but could you explain why it has to  be listed?

Comment: because functions in r can only return a single object like a vector. likewise, a list is technically a single object but can hold any number of other objects, in your case two vectors